# How can I fix this error: "npm WARN deprecated mimelib@0.3.1: This project is unmaintained"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Hoping you can help me figure mimelib out.
Trying to install this REACT script with my limited react xp and have a myriad of errors doing different things...

I'm running this script:
https://github.com/webdesignleader/referBeam

Getting this console error:

```
$ npm update
npm WARN deprecated mimelib@0.3.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated mailparser@0.6.2: Mailparser versions older than v2.3.0 are deprecated

changed 10 packages, and audited 760 packages in 27s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

48 vulnerabilities (4 low, 12 moderate, 27 high, 5 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Please help me fix this the right way.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. But just a `warning`, because `mimelib` package is not getting maintained anymore and you will not get any updates for it in the future. You can check over [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mimelib) as well.
Your project can still work. But this warning is basically telling you to remove this package as no one is maintaining it and I just checked it's not even updated from the last 5 years.

Comment: Okay thank you very much that is perfectly informative!

Now, if only I can figure out how to get the app working.
webpack seems to fail as well, with or without these errors.